# SQL Azure Transaction Deadlocks on Select Insert On Analysis Loop

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, azure-functions, database-deadlocks

I have a situation where I'm using a Web Function to generate a set of report data within SQL Azure.

To do this, I'm doing some fairly intense select queries with some aggregation formula, and inserting the results into a new flattened table.  This in itself is not causing any problems, however we often generate multiple reports at the same time with slightly different paramaters that interrogate the same basic set of underlying source data.

Thus, we get multipe web functions hitting the database in quick succession, calculating summary data based on the same set of underlying records.  Transaction Deadlocks like the example below are now common.

`Transaction (Process ID 96) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

I've tried using hints in my select queries like `WITH (NOLOCK)` however this seems to have had limited success.  Throttling my web functions helps, but I still get transaction deadlocks, and it gets worse if the database is under load.

Has anyone faced this situation before and have suggestions?  I really don't need any transaction locking at all when undertaking this operation.

An example of the type of queries executed are listed below.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserSurveyReportData
( SurveyQuestionID
, UserSurveyID
, SurveyID
, AnswerMeanRole
, SurveyScaleID ....)
SELECT SurveyQuestionID
, UserSurveyID
, SurveyID
, AnswerMeanRole
, SurveyScaleID ...
FROM viewReport
WHERE UserSurveyID = @UserSurveyID
```

The viewReport is a standard view made up of a few based tables, as well as some predefined functions that perform some calculations like:

```
-- AnswerMeanRole Calculation
DECLARE @Result Float
SELECT @Result = AVG(AnswerNumeric) FROM viewAnswersOptimised WHERE UserSurveyID = @UserSurveyID AND SurveyQuestionID = @SurveyQuestionID AND AnswerNumeric > 0 And IsComplete = 1 AND ParticipantRoleID = @ParticipantRoleID
RETURN CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,6), @Result)
```

Is there a way of turning off transaction locks when undertaking certain queries or calculations?  By the time I'm querying the underlying data, no further changes are being made.

I've done some reading around TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL and covering indexes, however I'm not sure of the best path forward.  We also have quite a few indexes (some manually added, some suggested by SQL Azure).

Comment: You will get a lot of feedback re with (nolock) and the potential for dirty reads. tl'dr its not  recommended. I would take a look at READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isolation level and experiment.  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Comment: Many thanks @MattEvans - after a quick skim, that article looks very promising!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing complete details about the view definition and where the deadlock occurs, I am suggesting few general suggestions:

1. Instead of ViewReport, I would suggest you to have table valued user defined function, which is internally using Tablevariables for the logic. Tablevariables will be a local copy of every user and there will not be any blocking/locking scenarios.
2. In the base tables where the deadlock is occurring, I would suggest to create covering indexes, so read queries can use the covering indexes, instead of blocking/locking the main table.
3. Keep transactions in the base tables as small as possible, to release locks sooner.
4. Always process the base tables in the same order, to avoid deadlock scenarios
5. Instead of view, you can also think of going for stored procedure with temp tables used inside. Temp tables will be separate for different user sessions. Also, temp tables will have statistics and indexes can be created to make the processing faster.

Comment: Thanks @venkataraman-r I appreciate its hard to really know given the complexity of the situation with just a small amount of detail in the question.  I do like the idea of creating a Table Variable to isolate each round of calculations.  Many of the other ideas have been implemented already but its good to know these are best practise.

Comment: @DaveA, glad my inputs helped.